# How to store dynamically generating Textviews values in Shared preferences Android

Tags: android, android-preferences, shared

I am querying the android Contact class and able to fetch contact name plus number and able to add multiple textviews in linear layout with number and name of the contact and able to save single textview number value in shared preferences and retrive it, how can I save dynamically adding textviews array of values (phone numbers (strings) in shared preferences. If any one provide sample code it will help me a lot, as I am doing this for the first time, by the way i searched a lot about this topic but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
public class Cont extends Fragment {
    protected static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
    Button showConts;
    TextView[] resultTextView;
    ViewGroup addItems;
    final int N = 1; 
    String name;
    String cNumber;
    String[] array;
    String nameContact;
    String number;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View contViews = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cont, container, false);
        addItems = (LinearLayout) contViews.findViewById(R.id.adds);
         showConts = (Button) contViews.findViewById(R.id.opens);
         resultTextView =  new TextView[N]; //create an empty array;

            // create a new textview
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
                resultTextView = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;
                addItems.addView(rowTextView);
                resultTextView[i] = rowTextView;
                if(resultTextView[i] != null ){
                    resultTextView[i].setText(nameContact+ " "+ cNumber);
                }
            }

         showConts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
               startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

            }
        });
        return contViews;
    }
    @Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ 
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(reqCode)
        {
           case (PICK_CONTACT):
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
             {
                 Uri contactData = data.getData();
                 Cursor c = getActivity().managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                  if (c.moveToFirst())
                  {
                      String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                      String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                      if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) 
                      {
                          Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                          phones.moveToFirst();
                          cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                           //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           nameContact  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                              final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
                              LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                              params.setMargins(0,0,0,10);
                              resultTextView = new TextView[N];
                              rowTextView.setTextSize(34);
                              rowTextView.setHeight(140);
                              rowTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                              rowTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7d3f98"));
                              rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                              //rowTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corn);
                              addItems.addView(rowTextView);
                              resultTextView[i] = rowTextView;
                              resultTextView[i].setLayoutParams(params);
                              if(resultTextView[i] != null ){
                                  resultTextView[i].setText(nameContact+ " "+ cNumber);
                              }
                              resultTextView[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String res1 = rowTextView.getText().toString();
                                     System.out.println("num " + res1.length());
                                    res1 = res1.split(" ")[res1.split(" ").length - 1];

                                    startDialActivity(res1);
                                }

                                private void startDialActivity(String result) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+result));
                                    startActivity(intent);  
                                }
                            });

                      }
                 }  
           }
        }}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try google PreferenceActivity, you don't have to,you can just use the traditional way(SharedPreference sp =new ....)
, but I think SharedPreferenceActivity is very easier, it's native,very simple and powerfull!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a JSONArray and add name and phone number by making JSONObject and add these JSONObjects to the JSONArray.

```
JSONObject mainObject=null;
        try{
            mainObject=new JSONObject();
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                JSONObject objName = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject objPhone = new JSONObject();
                objName.put("name", new String("abbcc"));
                objPhone.put("phone", new String("dfdfgdf"));
                arr.put(i,objName);
                arr.put(i,objPhone);
            }
            mainObject.put("mainObj",arr);
            System.out.println(mainObject.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    shared.edit().putString("details",mainObject.toString()).commit();
```

and then get string from sharedPreferences wherever you want and the get details from JSONObject and JSONArray

Comment: Thanks for your answer Akash, I will try it.